# WPF visual display VS Adobe Director

Tags: wpf, adobe

We are having a small argument...

There is a old dev team here that produced a kiosk application using Adobe Director technology.

Few months ago there was a decision to migrate the application to the new WPF technology. A new dev team was originated, and in these days we are able to see the flow of the new WPF application.

The first impression we got from the "old" team is that because it is about vector graphic - *"it can never looks the same as our good and old Adobe Director app"* (Which is bitmap base)

Well,  IS THIS TRUE? 
Couldn't the gradient be the same gradient ?
Are Hexa defined color looks deifrent ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like the old dev team is biased. I would say vector images are almost always better because they scale better. You can scale a vector image and have it remain clean and crisp.

The primary advantage of raster images is that they take less disk space (depending on the resolution of course).